# What exactly the getter and setter method does?

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, help

How and why getter adn setter methods are used in apex?
For Ex: What does this line of code does?
Public String companyname{get;set;}
And where in your code these methods be ideally used?

Answer (score 1):

There's already a question with an answer [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000092DMIAY) which offers a really good explanation into getters and setters, where and how they should be used. There's also an explantion right [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9167/getter-setter-confused?rq=1) on Stack Exchange!

Have a read of those, they'll definately bring you up to speed on what it is they do!

Hope this'll help!

Comment: In other words it's a duplicate! Generally you should vote to close in that case, even if this answer is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Setter :  set data from VF page component to class variable . 
Getter : get data from class variable to VF page Component. 
Action : Apex Class Methods which perform some operation

**Execution Flow**

When Page Loaded or refresh :    Constructor -->     Getter

When action is called(For ex Command button) :  Setter    -->   Action  -->   Getter

when you specify a data Member in apex class like `Public String companyname{get;set;}` internally how getter and setter invoked you can check by this example.... here i define getter and setter manually for num1, num2..
Here is a simple example that would be helpful for you....

[image]

```
    <apex:pageBlockSection >
          <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                 <apex:outputText value="Enter First Value"/>
                 <apex:inputText value="{!num1}"/>
         </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>                  <br/>
         <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputText value="Enter Second Value"/>
                 <apex:inputText value="{!num2}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>                   <br/>

        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:commandButton value="Add" action="{!addition}"/>          
      </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>               <br/>

          <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputText value="The Result ="/>
                 <apex:outputText value="{!res}" />
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

     </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Class

```
public class Addclass {

      integer num1;
      integer num2;
      integer res;

    public AddClass () {
       num1=num2=res=0; 
    }  
    public integer getnum1() {
       return num1;
    }          
    public integer getnum2() {
       return num2;
    }
    public integer getres() {
       return res;
    }
    public void setNum1(Integer n1){
       num1 = n1;
    }
    public void setNum2(Integer n2){
       num2 = n2;
    }
    public void addition(){

        res=num1+num2;          
    }   
}
```